# Split contents of dBase text field into words at " ", "-" or "_", capitalise first letters, and replace " " with "_"

Tags: arcpy, field-calculator, python-parser

A shapefile field has text with words separated by blanks " ", dashes "-" and underscores "_". I want to standardise the words to capitalise each word, and then replace spacese (" ") with underscores.

In can do this with one type of word separator (underscores) with

```
arcpy.CalculateField_management(in_table="xxx.dbf", field="temp", expression="' '.join([i.capitalize() for i in !inField!.split('_', '-')]).replace(' ','_')", expression_type="PYTHON_9.3", code_block="")
```

but this causes words separated by spaces or dashes to not be capitalised.

I have looked at using the re package but don't know how to call `re.split`, which should allow splitting on multiple separators.

Answer (score 2):

The easiest is probably to chain replace:

```
import arcpy
fc = r'C:\data.gdb\features'
fieldnames = ['infield','newfield']

with arcpy.da.UpdateCursor(fc, fieldnames) as cursor:
    for row in cursor:
        row[1] = '_'.join(row[0].replace('-',' ').replace('_', ' ').split()).title()
        cursor.updateRow(row)
```

Answer (score 0):

Building on the code in @BERA’s answer, and looking at the help for re (https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html), does it by using only spaces, dashes and underscores:

```
import re
fc = r'my dbf file'
fieldnames = ['inField','outField']
with arcpy.da.UpdateCursor(fc, fieldnames) as cursor:
    for row in cursor:
        row[1] = '_'.join(re.split(r"[\b \- \_']+", row[0])).title()
        cursor.updateRow(row)
```

Comment: The regex expression includes some unnecessary and duplicative characters in the set.  Either `[ \-\_]` or `[\s\-\_]` works.